# Does the internal layout of the Snowpiercer train require lots of suspension of disbelief?

Tags: snowpiercer, snowpiercer-2020

I have started watching the *[Snowpiercer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowpiercer_(TV_series))* series on Netflix. Already during the second episode, I am starting to wonder whether the featured interior is supposed to make any sense geometrically.

Basically, the Snowpiercer train is portrayed as some kind of a moving city with all the different locations (different train cars) lined up in a long row. The characters are seen going forth and back between various cars. This implies that they can completely traverse the length of each car.

Now, what we have actually seen of various cars appears to somehow contradict that:

- Based on the looks of the interior, the main hall of the "Night Car" is apparently supposed to occupy the entire width of the car. Also, it looks like it is some two storeys tall.
- The cattle car interior looks quite wide, as well. However, Layton and Till are not allowed in (and thus neither through).
- The cryostasis chambers also appear to occupy a considerable length and width.

So, how can the entire train be traversed? Is there a second level that allows unrestricted crossing? Early on, we once saw Layton (I think) climb down somewhere, but it didn't look like a long corridor, either. What is more, the proportions of the train do not look markedly different from nowadays' trains, and at least [the information from this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66413/how-long-is-the-train-in-the-snowpiercer) implies the train cars are supposed to be comparable to nowadays's train cars.

Thus, with various car interiors established as being at least 1.5 storeys tall, there is simply no space left for an additional connection corridor level underneath, nor for a connection corridor that runs alongside the (also quite wide) interiors.

**Is this supposed to make any sense? Is that something that was reasonable in the graphic novel and/or the movie, but was messed up for the series?**

As someone travelling on real trains on a daily basis, I am having a hard time wrapping my mind around what is portrayed there (unless I assume it has some inside-bigger-than-outside future technology/magic).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, the Snowpiercer has some sort of "maintenance service corridor", consisting in a underlevel under the main level. In said underlevel, there's a small "cableway" going back and forth across all the Snowpiercer.

There are multiple instances of people going to the underlevel for various reasons. Travelling, maintenance, carrying supplies, running away from justice...

- In the [SE101 16:30](https://www.netflix.com/watch/80177378), you can see a group of people traversing the Snowpiercer by using the underlevel "cableway".
- In the [S1E04 36:30](https://www.netflix.com/watch/80245138), you can see someone accessing the underlevel of the Snowpiercer, and multiple people coming from other cars in the Snowpiercer.

So there's definitely a way to traverse the Snowpiercer without walking by the main corridor.

---

As for the other part of the question... Definitely some degree of suspesion of disbelief is required for the series. Taking for reference one of the initial drawings in the opening of the series:

[image: Drawing of the Snowpiercer moving along through a snowy night; one of the side doors is open revealing a bright white light and two characters stand looking out]

There's absolutely no way there's room for a 2nd level under the main corridor in the Snowpiercer where you can be standing tall **and** there's enough room for you to jump up and down if you want to, as we can see in the series.

Besides, some of the cars are way too big on the inside. For example, the "Night Car", as you've said, is ridiculously big, both in width and height. And it has even more rooms inside besides the main hall.

[image: Night Car, Snowpiercer: a man in a suit stands in a circle of people sat down all looking at him, he is in a dark room with neon lights like an older nightclub; it had pillars on either side running its length]

Two levels in the Main Hall, **plus** a bunch of side rooms, **plus** the underlevel with the trolley? Yeah, no way.

Comment: The exterior shot at the end of Episode 10, makes it look larger. Though that last shot doesn't match very well with the journey downtrain just minutes earlier.

Answer (score 9):

[image][image][image][image]The specifications on Snowpiercer for the train cars are quite diverse, more so than you’d expect. Let us remember that this train was built with the intent to serve as a cruise liner travelling the world and visiting cities along the way, so as you might expect, some cars seem much more luxurious than the others.

In this case I think it’s safe to assume that the more luxurious cars such as the first class cabins, the first class dining hall, the aquarium + sushi bar, and the night car were part of the original design (pre freeze). There is a moment in the first few episodes of season one where Melanie and Audrey are talking and Melanie says something along the lines of “I remember when you shared your vision of the night car, Wilford saw booze and I saw a higher purpose” implying, that it had served passengers pre freeze.

The train is huge. The first class cars and the night car are by far the biggest, each supporting 3 levels (4 including the mechanics and hydraulics passage located just above the wheels, as seen in season 1 episode 6). The 3 levels consist of the 1st, 2nd and sub trail level. I have included a few images where I have lined of a rough idea and labelled where each level is most likely located. Rough measurements can also be seen in the image at the bottom.

Now if you watch carefully (they do wonders with camera angles) the side rooms in the night car (where the passengers have their epiphanies?) run vertically down the car, as you would expect. None of these rooms venture of horizontally. Again they do a great job with camera angles.

Another point of interest are the ‘chains’. These are easily 2 story cars. Probably almost identical to the height of the first class cabins. We know this because originally these selected cars held containers full of supplies stacked onto one another (and containers are huge) and as the years went on, they emptied said containers and were then converted into what we now know as the chains.

The cars we see the most, like the battery cars, the tail and the third class cars are all one story (I’m not counting the sub train as a story as each train car supports it) and we know that for sure. The tail and, again the container cars, were most likely tacked on towards the end of the freeze in a hurry.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

There is a rather simple explanation to this height debate. The sub train does not travel the FULL length of the train. As seen in the tail. There is no sub train there. As for first class. There is also no sub train there because it is a short section of the train. So in some places the car is just the full length floor to ceiling with some maintenance passages underneath most likely.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any evidence for this?  See how the other answers cite specific details in support.  Also, since you're assuming, without establishing, the cable-way, it appears you're responding to the other answers instead of the question; please make sure you direct your response to the question.  You might want to take the [tour].